# Paging not working correctly in Radgrid VB.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, telerik, telerik-grid, radgrid

Hello Everybody I'm using Radgrid to view data from the database with (Paging"NextPrevNumericAndAdvanced", Sorting, Filtering, and grouping) but paging does not work correctly
Ex. I wanted to go to page 27 when I click on button 27 it views page 8 only when I choose a Page number greater than 10

code and Design >>>

```
 <telerik:RadGrid runat="server" Width="100%" BorderColor="White" CssClass="border-dark" ID="RadGridDeliveryListNew" PagerStyle-BackColor="White" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" ShowGroupPanel="True" AllowFilteringByColumn="True">
                            <ExportSettings Excel-Format="ExcelML" SuppressColumnDataFormatStrings="true" FileName="Delivery List New" IgnorePaging="true" ExportOnlyData="true" OpenInNewWindow="true">
                            </ExportSettings>
                            <GroupingSettings CaseSensitive="false" />
                            <HeaderStyle Font-Size="Small" />
                            <ItemStyle BackColor="White" Height="40px" />
                            <FilterItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            <PagerStyle Mode="NextPrevNumericAndAdvanced" BackColor="White"></PagerStyle>
                            <AlternatingItemStyle BackColor="#fafafa" Height="40px" />
                            <ClientSettings AllowDragToGroup="True"></ClientSettings>
                            <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="dvry_DeliveryId" TableLayout="Fixed" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                                <Columns>
//DATA
 </Columns>
                            </MasterTableView>
                        </telerik:RadGrid>



      Protected Sub RadGridDeliveryListNew_SortCommand(sender As Object, e As GridSortCommandEventArgs) Handles RadGridDeliveryListNew.SortCommand
        Dim commandArguments As Object = e.CommandArgument
        Dim canceled As Boolean = e.Canceled
        Dim commandName As String = e.CommandName
        Dim source As Object = e.CommandSource
        Dim item As GridItem = e.Item


        Dim CRMCLs As New CRMCls.CRMClass
        If Session("Team") = "ShowroomsManager" Or Session("Team") = "SalesManager" Then
            CompainNew.Visible = True
            RadGridDeliveryListNew.DataSource = CRMCLs.FillNewDelivery("CreatedDate Descending")
            RadGridDeliveryListNew.DataBind()
        ElseIf Session("Team") = "ShowroomManager" Or Session("Team") = "Sales" Then
            CompainNew.Visible = True
            RadGridDeliveryListNew.DataSource = CRMCLs.FillNewDeliveryBranch("CreatedDate Descending", Session("Branch"))
            RadGridDeliveryListNew.DataBind()
        End If


    End Sub
    Protected Sub RadGridDeliveryListNew_GroupsChanging(sender As Object, e As GridGroupsChangingEventArgs) Handles RadGridDeliveryListNew.GroupsChanging
        Dim action As GridGroupsChangingAction = e.Action
        Dim canceled As Boolean = e.Canceled
        Dim expression As GridGroupByExpression = e.Expression
        Dim sortedFiled As GridGroupByField = e.SortedField
        Dim swapExpression As GridGroupByExpression = e.SwapExpression
        Dim tableView As GridTableView = e.TableView

        Dim CRMCLs As New CRMCls.CRMClass
        If Session("Team") = "ShowroomsManager" Or Session("Team") = "SalesManager" Then
            CompainNew.Visible = True
            RadGridDeliveryListNew.DataSource = CRMCLs.FillNewDelivery("CreatedDate Descending")
            RadGridDeliveryListNew.DataBind()
        ElseIf Session("Team") = "ShowroomManager" Or Session("Team") = "Sales" Then
            CompainNew.Visible = True
            RadGridDeliveryListNew.DataSource = CRMCLs.FillNewDeliveryBranch("CreatedDate Descending", Session("Branch"))
            RadGridDeliveryListNew.DataBind()
        End If
    End Sub


    Private Sub RadGridDeliveryListNew_PageIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As GridPageChangedEventArgs) Handles RadGridDeliveryListNew.PageIndexChanged
        RadGridDeliveryListNew.CurrentPageIndex = e.NewPageIndex
        Dim CRMCLs As New CRMCls.CRMClass
        If Session("Team") = "ShowroomsManager" Or Session("Team") = "SalesManager" Then
            CompainNew.Visible = True
            RadGridDeliveryListNew.DataSource = CRMCLs.FillNewDelivery("CreatedDate Descending")
            RadGridDeliveryListNew.DataBind()
        ElseIf Session("Team") = "ShowroomManager" Or Session("Team") = "Sales" Then
            CompainNew.Visible = True
            RadGridDeliveryListNew.DataSource = CRMCLs.FillNewDeliveryBranch("CreatedDate Descending", Session("Branch"))
            RadGridDeliveryListNew.DataBind()
        End If

    End Sub


    Private Sub RadGridDeliveryListNew_PageSizeChanged(sender As Object, e As GridPageSizeChangedEventArgs) Handles RadGridDeliveryListNew.PageSizeChanged
        Dim canceled As Boolean = e.Canceled
        Dim commandArguments As Object = e.CommandArgument
        Dim commandName As String = e.CommandName
        Dim source As Object = e.CommandSource
        Dim item As GridItem = e.Item
        Dim newPageSize As Integer = e.NewPageSize

        Dim CRMCLs As New CRMCls.CRMClass
        If Session("Team") = "ShowroomsManager" Or Session("Team") = "SalesManager" Then
            CompainNew.Visible = True
            RadGridDeliveryListNew.DataSource = CRMCLs.FillNewDelivery("CreatedDate Descending")
            RadGridDeliveryListNew.DataBind()
        ElseIf Session("Team") = "ShowroomManager" Or Session("Team") = "Sales" Then
            CompainNew.Visible = True
            RadGridDeliveryListNew.DataSource = CRMCLs.FillNewDeliveryBranch("CreatedDate Descending", Session("Branch"))
            RadGridDeliveryListNew.DataBind()
        End If
    End Sub


    Private Sub RadGridDeliveryListNew_ItemCommand(sender As Object, e As GridCommandEventArgs) Handles RadGridDeliveryListNew.ItemCommand
        Dim CRMCls As New CRMCls.CRMClass
        If e.CommandName = "ViewProdDet" Then
            Dim DeliveryID As Label = CType(e.Item.FindControl("LblID"), Label)

            Session("DeliveryID") = DeliveryID.Text.Trim

            Response.Redirect("~/Pages/Menu/Delivery/SummaryDelivery.aspx", False)
        End If
    End Sub


    Private Sub RadGridDeliveryListNew_PreRender(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadGridDeliveryListNew.PreRender
        If RadGridDeliveryListNew.IsExporting Then
            For Each GridFilteringItem In RadGridDeliveryListNew.MasterTableView.GetItems(GridItemType.FilteringItem)
                GridFilteringItem.Visible = False
            Next
        End If
    End Sub


    Protected Sub RadGridDeliveryListNew_NeedDataSource(sender As Object, e As GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs) Handles RadGridDeliveryListNew.NeedDataSource
        Dim CRMCls As New CRMCls.CRMClass
        If Session("Team") = "ShowroomsManager" Or Session("Team") = "SalesManager" Then
            CompainNew.Visible = True
            RadGridDeliveryListNew.DataSource = CRMCls.FillNewDelivery("CreatedDate Descending")

        ElseIf Session("Team") = "ShowroomManager" Or Session("Team") = "Sales" Then
            CompainNew.Visible = True
            RadGridDeliveryListNew.DataSource = CRMCls.FillNewDeliveryBranch("CreatedDate Descending", Session("Branch"))

        End If
    End Sub


    Protected Sub DeliveryListNew_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        'Dim alternateText As String = TryCast(sender, ImageButton).AlternateText

        'RadGridNewInc.ExportSettings.Excel.Format = DirectCast([Enum].Parse(GetType(GridExcelExportFormat), alternateText), GridExcelExportFormat)
        RadGridDeliveryListNew.ExportSettings.IgnorePaging = True
        RadGridDeliveryListNew.ExportSettings.ExportOnlyData = True
        RadGridDeliveryListNew.ExportSettings.OpenInNewWindow = True
        RadGridDeliveryListNew.ExportSettings.SuppressColumnDataFormatStrings = True
        RadGridDeliveryListNew.AllowFilteringByColumn = True
        RadGridDeliveryListNew.MasterTableView.ExportToExcel()
    End Sub


    Private Sub RadGridDeliveryListNew_Init(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadGridDeliveryListNew.Init
        Dim CRMCls As New CRMCls.CRMClass
        If Session("Team") = "ShowroomsManager" Or Session("Team") = "SalesManager" Then
            CompainNew.Visible = True
            RadGridDeliveryListNew.DataSource = CRMCls.FillNewDelivery("CreatedDate Descending")
            RadGridDeliveryListNew.DataBind()
        ElseIf Session("Team") = "ShowroomManager" Or Session("Team") = "Sales" Then
            CompainNew.Visible = True
            RadGridDeliveryListNew.DataSource = CRMCls.FillNewDeliveryBranch("CreatedDate Descending", Session("Branch"))
            RadGridDeliveryListNew.DataBind()
        End If
    End Sub


    Private Sub RadGridDeliveryListNew_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridItemEventArgs) Handles RadGridDeliveryListNew.ItemDataBound
        If TypeOf e.Item Is GridDataItem Then
            Dim LAteNote As LinkButton = CType(e.Item.FindControl("LinkButton5"), LinkButton)
            Dim LbtnDanger As LinkButton = CType(e.Item.FindControl("LbtnDanger"), LinkButton)

            If LAteNote.Text = "Y" Then
                LbtnDanger.Visible = True
            Else
                LbtnDanger.Visible = False
            End If
        End If


    End Sub
```

Comment: Are there definitely 27 pages, or is the displayed number of the last page wrong?

Comment: 30 pages ... it happens when the pages more than 10 pages

Comment: 1) If you look at the rendered page in the browser, does it look like it should do the correct thing? 2) Does the number 10 appear anywhere in any of the code to do with fetching the data? 3) If you change the page size a lot, does it still fail for the same page number?

Comment: I cannot help but think that `IgnorePaging="true"` is an issue, as well as a lack of page size with something like `PageSize="15"` or something.